# How do i get all the weblinks from a website?

Tags: web, web-crawler, phpcrawl

I want to get all the links(web posts) available in website . And also if any new post is added to website I should be able get the link. I will be having list of 10 websites and the link extraction process needs to be run periodically.

Can some one help me how to get only post links and new post link that is added.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to write a php script (since you mentioned php) which is called by a cron-job periodically. Inside the script you can

Option 1: Define a `curl` commando which automatically fetches all the content of one url. (May be better if you have to deliver some information to the website with post-method.)

Option 2: Use `file_get_contents` function to get all contents

Than you can parse these result with a regular-expression to extract the parts you are interested in (for example search for something like `<div class=".post">...</div>`). After that you can add the information to your database or just check if the information is already there.